# ng-text-truncate.js on ng-repeat is affecting all instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the [ng-text-truncate.js](https://github.com/lorenooliveira/ng-text-truncate) library for 'addmore' text truncate. The libray is working fine but when I used it on an ng-repeat item, the ng-click is affect ALL the instance at the same time i.e if I click one item to open it, all other items are opened at the same time.

```
.directive( "ngTextTruncate", [ "$compile", "ValidationServices", "CharBasedTruncation", "WordBasedTruncation",
  function( $compile, ValidationServices, CharBasedTruncation, WordBasedTruncation ) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            text: "=ngTextTruncate",
            charsThreshould: "@ngTtCharsThreshold",
            wordsThreshould: "@ngTtWordsThreshold",
            customMoreLabel: "@ngTtMoreLabel",
            customLessLabel: "@ngTtLessLabel"
        },
        controller: function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
            $scope.toggleShow = function() {
                $scope.open = !$scope.open;
            };

            $scope.useToggling = $attrs.ngTtNoToggling === undefined;
        },
        link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {

            $scope.open = false;

            ValidationServices.failIfWrongThreshouldConfig( $scope.charsThreshould, $scope.wordsThreshould );

            var CHARS_THRESHOLD = parseInt( $scope.charsThreshould );
            var WORDS_THRESHOLD = parseInt( $scope.wordsThreshould );

            $scope.$watch( "text", function() {
                $element.empty();

                if( CHARS_THRESHOLD ) {
                        if( $scope.text && CharBasedTruncation.truncationApplies( $scope, CHARS_THRESHOLD ) ) {
                            CharBasedTruncation.applyTruncation( CHARS_THRESHOLD, $scope, $element );

                        } else {
                            $element.append( $scope.text );
                        }

                } else {

                    if( $scope.text && WordBasedTruncation.truncationApplies( $scope, WORDS_THRESHOLD ) ) {
                        WordBasedTruncation.applyTruncation( WORDS_THRESHOLD, $scope, $element );

                    } else {
                        $element.append( $scope.text );
                    }

                }
            } );
        }
    };
}] )



.factory( "ValidationServices", function() {
    return {
        failIfWrongThreshouldConfig: function( firstThreshould, secondThreshould ) {
            if( (! firstThreshould && ! secondThreshould) || (firstThreshould && secondThreshould) ) {
                throw "You must specify one, and only one, type of threshould (chars or words)";
            }
        }
    };
})



.factory( "CharBasedTruncation", [ "$compile", function( $compile ) {
    return {
        truncationApplies: function( $scope, threshould ) {
            return $scope.text.length > threshould;
        },

        applyTruncation: function( threshould, $scope, $element ) {
            if( $scope.useToggling ) {
                var el = angular.element(    "<span>" + 
                                                $scope.text.substr( 0, threshould ) + 
                                                "<span ng-show='!open'>...</span>" +
                                                "<span class='btn-link ngTruncateToggleText' " +
                                                    "ng-click='toggleShow()'" +
                                                    "ng-show='!open'>" +
                                                    " " + ($scope.customMoreLabel ? $scope.customMoreLabel : "More") +
                                                "</span>" +
                                                "<span ng-show='open'>" + 
                                                    $scope.text.substring( threshould ) + 
                                                    "<span class='btn-link ngTruncateToggleText'" +
                                                          "ng-click='toggleShow()'>" +
                                                        " " + ($scope.customLessLabel ? $scope.customLessLabel : "Less") +
                                                    "</span>" +
                                                "</span>" +
                                            "</span>" );
                $compile( el )( $scope );
                $element.append( el );

            } else {
                $element.append( $scope.text.substr( 0, threshould ) + "..." );

            }
        }
    };
}])



.factory( "WordBasedTruncation", [ "$compile", function( $compile ) {
    return {
        truncationApplies: function( $scope, threshould ) {
            return $scope.text.split( " " ).length > threshould;
        },

        applyTruncation: function( threshould, $scope, $element ) {
            var splitText = $scope.text.split( " " );
            if( $scope.useToggling ) {
                var el = angular.element(    "<span>" + 
                                                splitText.slice( 0, threshould ).join( " " ) + " " + 
                                                "<span ng-show='!open'>...</span>" +
                                                "<span class='btn-link ngTruncateToggleText' " +
                                                    "ng-click='toggleShow()'" +
                                                    "ng-show='!open'>" +
                                                    " " + ($scope.customMoreLabel ? $scope.customMoreLabel : "More") +
                                                "</span>" +
                                                "<span ng-show='open'>" + 
                                                    splitText.slice( threshould, splitText.length ).join( " " ) + 
                                                    "<span class='btn-link ngTruncateToggleText'" +
                                                          "ng-click='toggleShow()'>" +
                                                        " " + ($scope.customLessLabel ? $scope.customLessLabel : "Less") +
                                                    "</span>" +
                                                "</span>" +
                                            "</span>" );
                $compile( el )( $scope );
                $element.append( el );

            } else {
                $element.append( splitText.slice( 0, threshould ).join( " " ) + "..." );
            }
        }
    };
}]);

}());
```

Comment: Add your code to a plunker or something

Comment: This is the link to the library that I am using https://github.com/lorenooliveira/ng-text-truncate. My question is how do I make the ng-click inside that library's directive to apply to ONLY the individual item in an ng-repeat. The plugin works fine if used on a single item

Comment: Does the problem occur without `ng-text-truncate.js`?

Comment: You probably need a more sophisticated way of tracking which of your repeats is open (perhaps an array?), rather than just `$scope.open = true | false;`

Comment: No. The app works fine. Like I said, the ng-text-truncate.js is truncating the element as expected. When i click the 'more' button, that individual item open/slide down and reveals the 'less' button which is the expected functionality but the only problem is  all other items are ALSO open at the same time.

Comment: ... I was expecting every item to open/slide only when I click their 'more' button,

Comment: This is the function that's called inside ng-text-truncated to toggle the button:   controller: function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
                $scope.toggleShow = function() {
                    $scope.open = !$scope.open;
                };

                $scope.useToggling = $attrs.ngTtNoToggling === undefined;
            },

Comment: @ksav, any idea how I could implement that "..more sophisticated way of tracking which of your repeats is open" ?

Comment: Use $index of your ng-repeat to create and access an array.